# How to make Magento 2 store multilingual?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, language

I am using magento 2.1.3 and i want to make my store in ***English*** and ***Arabic***. Any suggestion to me.

Comment: You should create another store view and select Arabic as locale. Then you could show store switcher in the storefront header.